# Does this property of a function $f : 2^A \rightarrow A$ have a name?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I've got this property: For all $S\in 2^A$ and all partitions $P$ of $S$, $f(S) = f\left(\left\{f(M)\mid M \in P\right\}\right)$, i.e. $f$ maps a set of values to a single value and gives the same result whether we map the set "at once" or whether we map subsets first and then map the set of the results. Examples for $f$ would be sums of finite sets of numbers, or the least upper bound of subsets of a complete lattice.

So, if $A = \mathbb{N}\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$ and $f(S) = \sum_{s \in S} s$, the property is fulfilled, as, for example $f(\{1,2,3\}) = f(\{f(\{1,2\}),f(\{3\})\}) = 3+3 = 6$

Is that a well-known property? If so, what's it called so I can read up more on it?

Comment: The lack of explicit quantifiers makes your property hard to understand. Does your property say the following? *For every $S \in 2^A$ and for every partition $P$ of $S$, $f(S) = f\left(\left\{f(M)\mid M \in P\right\}\right)$*

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'll amend the question.

Comment: Use `\sum` if you are talking about a sum. Use `\Sigma` if you are writing in Greek.